# How to pass the linq returned xml data to another function?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, parameters

```
var serviceLine = from ServiceLine in DataXML.Descendants("Serviceline")
                              select new
                              {
                                  ServiceLineName = ServiceLine.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                  EntityName = ServiceLine.Attribute("Entity").Value,
                                  SiteLevelName = ServiceLine.Attribute("SiteLevel").Value,
                                  FolderName = ServiceLine.Descendants("Folder"),
                                  ItemName = ServiceLine.Descendants("Item")
                              };
```

i need to pass the serviceline as paramenter to another method, there i need to use the query returned result. so how can i pass the return. what type i need to use to pass the returned data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create you own type.
2. Use [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)
3. Return `object`, in calling method use [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) to access properties.

Comment: can u add some sample link with the answer.

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan, For which method?

Comment: <SummaryTask Name="2.0 Plan">
  <Task>2.1 Update planning and prepare for engagement kick off</Task> 
  <Task>2.2 Conduct one or more quality assurance procedures</Task> 
- <SummaryTask Name="a. Identify">
  <Task>1.1 Validate Requirements and Perform Engagement Specific Planning</Task> 
  </SummaryTask>
  </SummaryTask>
This is my xml i need t p pass this to some method.

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan, So, what's the problem? As I said, you have several options.